# bootstrap - _reboot.scss is overriding css

Tags: css

Ok I have looked for sometime and have yet to fully understand this file.  I was just about to finish up with a new Website when I noticed that all of the fonts had change from 16px to 1rem, too small for a mobile friendly site.  Why is this happening?? More importantly, how do I stop it?

```
body {
 font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica 
 Neue",Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI 
 Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
 font-size: 1rem;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 1.5;
 color: #212529;
 text-align: left;
}
```

This is the first time I have ever seen this file.  I would like to know from where it is coming, how to override it and prevent this in the future.

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you applying your reset CSS file after your own CSS? (e.g. If there are two identical selectors in the CSS that's delivered to your page, the last one will overwrite any previous ones)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. I added a contact form to the Website that I was working on and one of the style sheet references was causing the issue:

I still do not understand how this this works so I just deleted it and the site, font size, went back to normal. I have investigated the background on the idea and think it is a sound one. However, the implementation and documentation are very poor in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

To let you know what I believe is going on, it's possible you're importing Bootstrap 4 somewhere and this is importing the '_reboot.scss' file. Ensure you haven't imported Bootstrap if you don't want to use it. If you do want to use it, ensure you are only importing it at the very beginning of your application. This gives the rest of your pages room to override it if they need. However, if you import Bootstrap after some of your customer css has already been applied, it will likely override it.